# Using Bitbucket, how do I get commits from one branch into another?

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket

At my new job, where we use git with Bitbucket, we have a master branch, a new-features branch and a fix-these branch.

I've been making all my changes to the fix-these branch. After committing them, I push them to origin/fix-these using SourceTree. So far, so good.

In Bitbucket, how do I make the fix-these branch so that it includes the few commits that have been made recently to new-features? (And then I just "pull origin/fix-these" to make my local copy current, right?)

Comment: Your strategy should be to either `merge` or `rebase` the commits from `new-features` into the `fix-these` branch.  I'm assuming it will be fairly straightforward to do this using BitBucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim suggested, you'll want to merge new-features into fix-these.

You can do this on Bitbucket by navigating to the Compare page (see sidebar), selecting "fix-these" as destination, "new-features" as source and then hitting the Merge button in the top-right corner.

Answer (score 21):

Use git cherry pick. It lets you pick commit and add them over other branches.

```
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

Example:

```
git cherry-pick 123456
```

This will add the commit on the current branch.

Answer (score 5):

You cant, you'll have to use git commands. Would have been nice with a web interface for it like pull requests.

Comment: In 2020 Bitbucket still does not support a cherry-pick workflow in their web UI?  Sad.

Comment: 2022 and they still do not have it. :/

Comment: 2022 March still do not have it :D

Comment: 2023 March they still do not have it :)

Comment: 2024 and it's still not a thing